# Which Code Resource content type do I use to utilise ssjs/ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to use code resource page as a processing page and do not want any impression counts. The page  will include ssjs and ampscript. Should I be using the Javascript content type?

Comment: I don't think it matters. CloudPage impressions count against Super Messages, but not code resources (currently). If you want to serve an HTML page, set the Content-Type header explicitly... Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Type","text/html");

Comment: Hi @Macca, thanks for your reply. So if i choose javascript content type I can also include ampscript in this code resource page?

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't matter, @s3002068. The difference between the types of code resource sets the Content-Type but what you do inside the code resource is up to you.